# Derive an End date by Man hours and a start date in Excel-2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need a formula which calculates the End Date (with Time) when total **Man Hours** and **Start Date** are given. *[Excel 2010]*

**Criteria:**

1. 1 Man Day         = 8 Hours (1 hour is break time)
2. Work Start Time   = 10:00
3. Work End Time     = 19:00
4. 1 Man Week        = Mon - Fri
5. Holidays, if any, should not be counted

**For example:**

```
Cell E7 = Man Hours  = 10 Hrs 
Cell F7 = Start Date = 26-Jun-15 13:00
Cell G7 = End Date   = ???? (Ideally 29-Jun-15 14:00)
```

*27th and 28th are weekends

Thank you!

Comment: what have you tried so far? why the ideal end date is not `29-Jun-15 15:00` as per your description of break time? and why, for the love of Chronos, do you need hourly precision in the first place, if you are doing project planning, that is not going to work... at all...

Comment: Tried - WORKDAY(F7,E7/8)) , but this does not help in showing the time in spite of custom formatting. Time shows 12:00 in all cells. You're right in correcting it to 15:00. Guess the stress of resolving this had me overlook that error. Why hourly precision, well I was asked to depict it in the tasks sheet by my boss!!! Help me understand the challenges in showing it the way I want to. Please

Comment: who cares about challenges in showing it, it is just foolish to estimate the end of **duration** from the value of estimated **effort** in hourly granularity - daily granularity is fragile enough that planning methods have to introduce contingency time (or to use dimensionless effort estimates and iteration-granularity planning as in Agile)... `WORKDAY` is more than enough IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

margin of error for the estimate of duration from estimate of effort is too big for an hourly granularity to make any sense as long as real people and realistic plans are concerned

however, if we have an estimate of duration in working hours on the input (as opposed to calendar days/weeks/months which are more common units of duration estimates) and we need to calculate the end date-time, we could:

- compute helper column with the would-be end hour if there were no closing hours (e.g. in cell H7, in Excel Date units = fractions of a day)

  ```
  =MOD(F7, 1) + MOD(E7, 8)/24
  ```
- check if the would-be hour is before the closing hours and adjust the end day + end time accordingly. If it's after, move to the next workday and adjust time, e.g. for simplicity assume all breaks are at the beginning of a day, so we can subtract the number of hours in a workday:

  ```
  =IF(H7 <= 19/24,
     WORKDAY(F7, E7/8, holidays) + H7,
     WORKDAY(F7, E7/8 + 1, holidays) + H7 - 8/24)
  ```

[image: screenshot of example calculations]

Comment: update: use `<=` instead of `<` in the condition as 19:00 is still a valid time, I haven't updated screenshot where the formula works for 19:00 only due to rounding error

Comment: I see what your saying and agree to it more or less. In my own project plan I am using the formula 
=IF(F7="","",WORKDAY(F7,E7/8)) in G7 and 
=IF(F8="","",WORKDAY($F$7,SUM($E$7:E8)/8)) in G8 and drag it all the way. This does not however show the hours which is absolutely fine. Guess my Boss wants to out smart my plan :) Thank you for the help Aprillion. See you down the line again.

Answer (score 0):

assume you saved your national holidays on column I, you can try below in cell H7:

=IF(HOUR(F7+E7/24)>19,((F7+E7/24)-INT(F7+E7/24)-0.792)+(WORKDAY(F7,1,I:I))+0.417,F7+E7/24)

Comment: please explain the 0.792 and 0.417 constants

Comment: 0.792 is acually 19/24, 0.417 is 10/24
i add 10 hours to start time and see if it will go over 1900, if over 1900, formula'll calculate the time left to complete the job.  +workday means it'll return the next working day,+0.417 coz office hour start at 1000.  i'm wondering if there's any shorter formula can do the job... this is the one i think of only....

Comment: BTW, i totally agree with you why the end date is not 29-Jun-15 15:00 as he said there's 1 hour break....... is it just only for KPI report or what...@@

Comment: please note that using constants instead of simple calculations does NOT provide any benefits whatsoever - if you think the computation would be faster, then no, it won't be noticeably faster, not even half a second for millions of rows

Comment: should he just keep the office hours in 2 cells and always refer to the cell for calculation?

Comment: @ REII: Thanks for your response but this formula returns the same date as 26-Jun-15 when It should show 29-Jun-15. Refer my question for details.

Comment: @ZatinDharmapuri with =IF(HOUR(F7+E7/24)>19,((F7+E7/24)-INT(F7+E7/24)-19/24)+(WORKDAY(F7,1,I:I))+10/24+1/24,F7+E7/24), what i got is 6/29/2015 15:00